# Setting the selected item in a Spinner widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-spinner

In my Android app, I have an `Activity` with a `Spinner` widget. I created it with the following code in `onCreate()`:

```
    this.playerPositionSpinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.player_position_text);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> positionsAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.positions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    positionsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    this.playerPositionSpinner.setAdapter(positionsAdapter);
```

Later I want to set the selected item based on a String which I know is a valid item in the Spinner's list? All of the `Spinner.setSelection()` methods take an `int` parameter for the position. How do I obtain the position of a `String` in the `Spinner`s drop-down list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You have posted some code now! Yeah! This simplifies my example drastically.)
I recommend using [`Spinner#setSelection()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29) after calling `setAdapter()`:

```
playerPositionSpinner.setSelection(positionsAdapter.getPosition("Watermelon"));
```

Obviously you can replace `"Watermelon"` with something relevant for your app.

Comment: I apologize that my original question was a little vague. I have edited with some more details. Feel free to update your answer, if you feel it needs it.

Comment: @Code-Guru -- you can only call `setSelection` after you've assigned an `ArrayAdapter` to the Spinner.  I suggest declaring playerPositionSpinner as a class member, then assigning it during the `onCreate`, this way you will be able to call the spinner from other methods and inner classes

Comment: @mrres1 In the code that I added with my edit, the `this` reference in front of `playerPositionSpinner` should be a clue that it already is a class member.

Comment: I happen to be setting the selection in the `onCreate()` method where the code in my edited question lives. After looking at the API in more detail, I see that I can call `getAdapter()` on my `Spinner` if I needed to set the selection in another method. (Or I could store the `Adapter` as a class member, of course.)

Comment: I missed "**Later** I want to ..." Sorry, but you got it!

Comment: @Sam When I wrote that I forgot to check my code to see exactly where "later" was. I had it in my head that it was in a different method.

Answer (score 0):

Use your spinner setSelection method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int, boolean)

You need to pass it the integer value of the location of the item. to get the value use your adapter.

Comment: I apologize that my original question was a little vague. I have edited with some more details. Feel free to update your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to call `playerPositionSpinner.setSelection(position)` after creating and setting the Spinner's `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: How do either of these links answer the question? From Stack Overflow's policy on link-only answers: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."

Comment: I already looked at both of those and didn't find a solution to my problem. I probably should have added more details to my question.

Comment: This edit is an improvement over the links, but still doesn't answer my question about how to get the position when I have a String.

Comment: Ok, but now your answer is fundamentally the same as mine (and Sean's)... What new information is this contributing or is it a duplicate answer?

Comment: It's actually the triplicate answer to Sean and yours.  And apparently wrong.  So what are you contributing?

Comment: The answer: not only was it first but it addresses setting the selection from a `String` _not_ an `int`.

Comment: @mrres1 I'm not trying to attack you or discourage you from using this forum. I am certain you have strong knowledge to contribute. But this isn't your best answer. As it is now it does not provide any information that hasn't already been suggested and doesn't address the entire question. According to Stack Overflow policies, you ought to improve this answer by presenting new, useful suggestions or consider deleting it. (Again this isn't an attack, none of the down-votes are mine, I'm simply stating the terms of use.) Cheers!